# What's the appropriate place of "languages" in this sentence?

Tags: word-order, neither-nor

I'm trying to express this idea (not one not another, using nor and neither) but I do not know what is the most appropriate form in English. Is any order usually established for the position of the word **languages**? Or should I repeat the noun to what they refer to?

Proposals:

> 1.- Neither for minority **languages** nor for the dominant
>   2.- Neither for minority nor for the dominant **languages**
>   3.- Neither for minority **languages** nor for the dominant **ones**
>   4.- Neither for minority **languages** nor for the dominant **languages**

Comment: I cannot see why you mark only dominant languages as determinate. *Ceteris paribus*, I'd write "for neither minority nor dominant languages".

Answer (score 2):

1 is acceptable, but slightly artificial - it sounds 'poetical' because 'dominant' is a hanging adjective.
2 is fine, but formal. Appropriate for a paper. Slight sense of ambiguity because 'minority' can be a noun, but no real danger of misunderstanding.
3 is the most usual in any context. Unambiguous and perfect syntax.
4 is not acceptable in any context. The repetition of 'languages' would be regarded as clumsy at best and as unacceptable at worst by most native speakers.